# Node-gyp error while using install on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-modules, termux

how are you? I have some problems with npm install.
I tried to download `@discord/opus` but the result looks like this. Does anyone know any decision? If so, it can be said about the solution. Thanks you !

Image 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMHYi.png 
Image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVX9x.png 
Image 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayqo0.png 
Image 4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ6ga.png